# Como comparar 2 Celulas em colunas diferentes - SQL

Tags: sql, select

Preciso fazer um `SELECT` buscando alguns dados com a condição de que apenas se o valor de uma determinada `cell`for diferente de uma outra `cell`.

Ex:

```
+-----------+------+------+
| Descricao | Val1 | Val2 |
+-----------+------+------+
| hhhhhhhhh | 9999 | 9999 |
| yyyyyyyyy | 1111 | 2222 |
+-----------+------+------+
```

Gostaria de um `SELECT`que apenas buscasse a 2º `row`, onde o Val1 é diferente do Val2.

Comment: Como o Marlon citou, o ideal é utilizar o where >select * from tabela where val1 <> val2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar na condição (`where`) um operador de comparação entre as colunas.

```
select * from tabela where val1 <> val2
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o operador diferente `!=`

```
SELECT * FROM nome_tabela WHERE Val1 != Val2
```